# How do I solve ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in Angular?

Tags: angular, pipe

I'm trying to display movie categories and I get an Error: cannot read property of 'forEach' of undefined but my code runs as expected. I don't know why this errors pops up while I inspect in google chrome.

**Category-list.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'categoryList'
  })
  export class CategoryListPipe {
    transform(mediaItems) {
      var categories = [];
      mediaItems.forEach(mediaItem => {
        if (categories.indexOf(mediaItem.category) <= -1) {
          categories.push(mediaItem.category);
        }
      });
      return categories.join(', ');
    }
  }
```

**media-item-list.component.html**

```
<nav>
    <a (click)="getMediaItems('')">
      All
    </a>
    <a (click)="getMediaItems('Movies')">
      Movies
    </a>
    <a (click)="getMediaItems('Series')">
      Series
    </a>
  </nav>

  <header 
  [ngClass]="{'medium-movies':medium === 'Movies', 'medium-series':medium === 'Series'}">
   {{ medium }}
   {{ mediaItems | categoryList }} 
</header>

<section>
  <app-media-item
  [ngClass]="{'medium-movies': mediaItem.medium==='Movies', 'medium-series':mediaItem.medium==='Series'}" 
  *ngFor="let mediaItem of mediaItems"
  [mediaItem]="mediaItem"
  (delete)="onMediaItemDelete($event)"></app-media-item>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `transform` method of your pipe runs even before `mediaItems` are populated. That's why you're getting that error. But after that, since `mediaItems` get populated again and the `transform` method runs again, it's all working as expected.

To not get the error in the first place, in your pipe's `transform` method, check if `mediaItems` is defined. If it is defined, then only perform the operation. Send then `mediaItems` as is otherwise(as it's value is null).